# Multiple inputs into MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a MapReduce job which takes a number of delimited input sources. All sources contain the same information, but it may be in different columns and the separator may be different per source. The sources are parsed in the mapper by a configuration file. This configuration file allows users to confine these different separators and column mappings.

For example, input1 is parsed using configuration properties

```
input1.separator=,
input1.id=1
input1.housename=2
input1.age=15
```

where 1, 2 and 15 are the columns in input1 which relate to those properties.

So, the mapper needs to know which configuration properties to use for each input source. I can't hard code this as other people will be running my job and will want to add new inputs without requiring a compiler.

The obvious solution is to extract the file name from the splits and apply configuration that way.

For example, assume I'm inputting two files, "source1.txt" and "source2.txt". I could write my configuration like

```
source1.separator=,
source1.id=2
...
source2.separator=|
source2.id=4
...
```

The mapper would get the file name from the splits, and then read the configuration properties with the same prefix.

However, if I'm pointing to folders in a Hive warehouse, I can't use this. I could extract bits of the path and use those, but I don't really feel that's an elegant or sturdy solution. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: If you had different dirs for those files, u could've used `MultipleInputs`. But in this case pathExtraction seems to be the only way !

Comment: How would that be different from my proposed solution? I'm using MultipleInputs here. MultipleInputs doesn't provide any additional functionality for identifying folders than it does file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. It turns out that the order in which input sources (files or directories) are added to `FileInputFormat` is maintained, and then stored in the job context as `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir`. So, my solution

**Runner.java**

```
for(int i=X; i<ar.length; i++) {
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(ar[i]));
}
```

where *X* is the first integer at which an input path can be found.

**InputMapper.java**

```
#Get the name of the input source in the current mapper
Path filePath = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
String filePathString = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
#Get the ordered list of all input sources
String pathMappings = context.getConfiguration()
    .get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir");
```

As I know the order in which input sources are added to the job, I can then have the user set configuration properties using numbers, and map the numbers to the order in which input sources were added to the job in the CLI.

Comment: Or you could add the mapping of input source to order to the job context in the runner class and then access it in the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether `MultipleInputs` provides `PathFilter` integration. However you can extend one and feed matched files to different `Mapper` types based on your criteria.

```
FileStatus[] csvfiles = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path("hive/path"),
            new PathFilter() {
                public boolean accept(Path path) {
                    return (path.getName().matches(".*csv$"));
                }
            });
```

Assign handling Mapper to this list :

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, csvfiles[i].getPath(), 
                                 YourFormat.class, CsvMapper.class);
```

For each file type you have to provide the required regex. Hope you are good at it.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution as it requires modifying the job for new input sources and doesn't enable the mapper to identify which configuration to use for which source. All of my inputs will be processed by the same mapper class, I just need to know which configuration to use for each input based on some metadata characteristic of the input. I think you've misunderstood the question, so apologies if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: I got ur question right, but I don't think `MultipleInputs` or `Mapper` provides such api. Whats wrong with 2 mappers as you are processing them differently ? If you have some common and complex logic to put the map, just create an abstract class and extend it.

Comment: Because that "logic" (column mappings) has to be configurable on a per-input basis, for up to N different inputs. No recompiling is allowed if a new input is to be added.

Comment: then why u think, checking filenames inside mapper isn't elegant ? `MultiInputs` are used to set different mappers to different paths, not for this kinda stuff. You have no use of it in this case.